# How to add the doi link to the reference number (not the reference body)

Tags: bibliographies, packages, bibliographystyle

I need to add the doi link to the reference number so that the output looks like this:

[image]

I was able to modify the `.sty` file to add the same doi link to all references. Here is the part I modified by inserting `\href{doi-link}` inside the square brackets `[]`

```
%% Bibliography commands.
    \setlength\bibindent{.2in}
    \renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
         {\vskip 7pt \hrule \vskip-.5in \section*{\refname
            \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}}%
          \list{[\href{https://doi.org/10.1093/jeg/lbp036}{\@arabic\c@enumiv }]}
               {\settowidth\labelwidth{.25in}%
                \leftmargin\labelwidth
```

How do I get the doi field from each bibitem so that the doi link is updated for each reference?

Comment: You haven’t given us nearly enough information for us to help you. You say you’ve modified a style but don’t tell us what package you’re using not what bibliography style etc. Please edit your question to show a complete compilable document that shows what you are doing.